# STM32 SPI Register Write

Tags: stm32

My original function had multiple 8-bit writes (wdata variable) and value inside the same array. This was transmitted by SPI master to a register. Now l'm porting to a new project that needs 32-bit address on the slave.

Original:

```
void register_write(uint8_t value)
{

/* Initialize array */
uint8_t wdata[5];

/* Write command */
wdata[0] = 0x2F;

/* Register address */
wdata[1] = 0x45;
wdata[2] = 0x81;
wdata[3] = 0x23;

/* Data written to register */
wdata[4] = value;

HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, wdata, 5, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
```

Is this the correct way to modify my register write function for 32-bit address and keep my 8-bit value in the same array? I'm trying to avoid having 2 different HAL_SPI_Transmit for the register address and value.

Modified:

```
void register_write(uint8_t value)
{

/* Initialize array */
uint32_t wdata[2];

/* Write command */
wdata[0] = 0x2F458123;

/* Data written to register */
wdata[1] = value;

HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, wdata, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those two pieces of code are not even remotely similar.
And no, you don't need two HAL_SPI_Write commands if you do it properly.

The first code sends 5 bytes from an array of 5 bytes. The other code has an array of two 32-bit integers, or 8 bytes, but sends only two bytes out which must be invalid.

The conversion of 8-bit data to 32-bit data is also done incorrectly, as this is a little-endian system.

The latter code would send out <0x23, 0x81, 0x45, 0x25, data> which is also incorrect from your original code.